# How to call a function which is inside a class in React?

Tags: reactjs

How can i call a function which is inside a class ?
here is the code -

```
class FriendList extends Component {
    demoFunction()
    {
      console.log('Inside demo function')
    }
    render(){
    <div>Hello</div>
    }
}

    const button= () => {
      return (
    <button onClick={() => demoFunction()}>Button</button>//How can i call demo function here?
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what are you trying to do by calling a function of a React Component from another component. I strictly feel you are on the wrong track. But still if want to do that, you can do like this:

```
class FriendList extends Component {
  static demoFunction() {
    console.log('Inside demo function')
  }

  render() {
    <div>Hello</div>
  }
}

const button = () => {
  return (
    <button onClick={() => FriendList.demoFunction()}>Button</button>
  )
}
```

Just declare **demoFunction** as **static** function and call this with the help of class name i.e **FriendList.demoFunction()**